# Gmail: How to open emails in an 'independent' new tab?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

When using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> to open emails in new tabs they are 'dependent' on the tab from which they were opened, which I don't want.

#### Example of problem:

1. From **Tab 1: Gmail inbox** I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> an email, and it opens in **Tab 2: Email** with an URL on the form `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=btop&ver=...`
2. I close **Tab 1: Gmail inbox**, and **Tab 2: Email** also closes, which is undesired. There are some other similar undesired effects of this dependent mode.

When an email is opened normally with just a `Left Click` the URL is on the form `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/...` and the tab is completely independen of all other tabs.

I am looking for a convenient way of opening emails in new tabs that are independent from the tab from which it was opened.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Chrome or Firefox to close the main Gmail page while keeping messages open, but it does work in the Microsoft browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is the option to use old school basic view with URL: **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/**

[image]

then you can use freely even middle-button-mouse-click

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the `Print` button when viewing an individual email (icon that looks like a printer, in the upper right).

For me (Chrome browser), this brings up a simplified view of the email in a new tab, and a print dialog. Hitting `Cancel` on the print dialog leaves the tabbed view of the email, and this tab persists even when the main GMail tab is closed.